# Text on GUI Missing

Tags: raspbian, gui

Using the latest version of Raspbian as of this writing, on a RasPi 3 B+, suddenly the text no longer shows on many GUI objects, such as some tooltips, some context menus, Chromium tabs, the Package Installer and Updater, etc.

**Example screenshot:**
[image]

I'm not super experienced with Linux; only dabbled here and there as necessary. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: At a guess I would say you're running out of resources (especially with so many tabs open). How does it look straight after a reboot?

Comment: @Dirk Looking at my task manager it says there's plenty of free memory, and storage space (SDCard). It looks exactly the same after a reboot. Also, it happens outside of the browser as well.